# Calling python functions from MATLAB workers

Tags: python, matlab, simulink, parfor, gil

I'm trying to run a MATLAB script using parfor which runs a simulink model in parallel by sim function, and this simulink model contains a MATLAB Function Block.

The function defined in this block calls a python function using "py." mechanism.

Unfortunately, the run sometimes seems stuck in the middle, when I fed a large number of simulations.   The debugging output stops to show up.  I suspect a deadlock somewhere.

So, my questions are

- Can we run a simulink model which contains python functions in parallel?
- In what way MATLAB calls the python interpreter?  One for each MATLAB worker or One for the entire MATLAB?

I use MATLAB R2017b on Mac.

Addition of March 22, 2018:  I contacted to the support and they responded that calling a python function from a MATLAB function block in a simulink model is not supported and anything can happens.  Still I'm interested in how MATLAB interacts with (a) python interpreter(s).  Is there a single python interpreter which interacts with the whole MATLAB or are there multiple python instances for all MATLAB workers?

Addition of April 22, 2018: Updating MATLAB 2018a seems fix the problem

Comment: Good question indeed. What I know is that it is incredibly hard (if at all possible)  to have several python sub-interpreters working in parallel due to the Global Interpreter Lock (https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). 
Depending of the amont of effort to port the python code to matlab  script, it may be the easier and quickest way to solve your issue.

Comment: I suggest you put a schema to help understanding the architecture of your problem