# Matlab cell data can't be referenced from Simulink

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

From Matlab, I am calling a python function that returns a list, and I want to load those values into an array that I can pass out to Simulink to work with.  I can type code into the CommandWindow and get the results I expect:

```
>> myList = cell(py.myPyModule.myPyFunction());
>> disp(myList);
    [1]    [2]    [3]

>> disp(myList{1});
   1
```

However, if I put that same code into a Matlab function and call that function from Simulink, that last line gives me an error:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Is there some difference in the two cases?  I can't figure out any way to actually get the data out in the case where I call a Matlab function from Simulink.

Comment: Try `cell2mat` to turn it into a numeric array.

Comment: Seems the MATLAB Function block can't really use python: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49354940/2732801

Comment: @Cris, could you post that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?  That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Daniel, the post you reference indicate that the problem was fixed with 2018a.  Still, point taken, and I would think carefully before adding python to simulink in a production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, [Simulink doesn't support cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/data-types-supported-by-simulink.html). Your function should convert your data to a numeric array to be used in Simulink. You can use the [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) function for this.